# Material-ui popup state popover not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I used `material-ui-popup-state` package to add customised menus on my header. I'm using code similar to the code in [the documentation](https://github.com/jcoreio/material-ui-popup-state#popover-1). The difference is only in the content of the popover. Mine has a few cards in the content and some styling for the background. There are two of these popovers in my header each with its own trigger.

The problem is that the popover does not behave as expected at all times and closes when the user hovers on the content of the popover. The behaviour is not consistent and is intermittent. One  pattern I observed is that this happens most often when one moves from content of one popover to the button that triggers the other one.

Is this a known issue, is there any work-around?

[Sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-pond-2gm6j?file=/pages/index.js)

Comment: you should also provide your implementation somewhere so folk can see your problem better

Comment: @ducmai Added sample codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself. Posting for anyone looking for the answer.

```
<PopupStateController variant="popover" popupId={"label1"}>
          {(popupState) => {
            return popupState.isOpen ?
              <>
                {
                  <Box key={1} {...bindHover(popupState)}>
                    {dispBox}
                  </Box>
                }
                <HoverPopover
                  TransitionComponent={Grow}
                  key={2}
                  {...bindPopover(popupState)}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "left"
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "left"
                  }}
                  PaperProps={{
                    square: true
                  }}
                  TransitionProps={{ timeout: { enter: 500 } }}
                  elevation={1}
                >
                  {popupContent}
                </HoverPopover>
              </>: null
            );
          }}
        </PopupStateController>
```

I'm not sure why this works but it solved my issue. My guess is that it prevents the multiple `<HoverPopover />`s from interfering with each other by removing the elements from the tree when not open.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package:

npm install material-ui-popup-state

Source: https://copypaste.guru/WhereIsMyJavascriptModule/how-to-fix-module-not-found-can-t-resolve-material-ui-popup-state